# How do I round up numbers when updating global prices in Magento using PHP script?

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.4

I have the following script in my magento root directory for updating the prices of all products in the store which was kindly suggested by a stack overflow member: This adds 3% to all product prices but does not round the number ?

```
<?php 
require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $product->setPrice($product->getPrice()* 1.03);
    $product->save();
}
?>
```

I have tried some php code such as ceil and round but don't really know how to make it work with this code , any help would be appreciated many thanks

Comment: ceil should work fine to round up.  `ceil($product->getPrice()* 1.03)`

Comment: What are you trying to round to?

Comment: @Dave example: 10.34 to 10:40 many thanks

Comment: @Ledgemonkey so you're only wanting to round the number after the decimal?

Comment: @Henesnarfel yes correct I've tried your suggestion > ceil($product->setPrice($product->getPrice()* 1.03)); but does not round ? thanks

Comment: @Ledgemonkey the ceil function rounds the entire number up to the nearest whole number. round is the function you need.  see Max's answer below it seems to be what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
    ;
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $oldPrice = $product->getPrice();
    $increase = 1.03;
    $newPrice = round($oldPrice * $increase , 1);// rounds to the nearest $0.10
                                                 // so $183.34 rounds to $183.30
    $product->setPrice($newPrice);
    $product->save();
}
```

You don't need to close the PHP tag if you don't want to write inline HTML.

Comment: many thanks for your help it seems to be working great ! you did miss out ->addAttributeToSelect('price') but I have edited the code , not often that happens !! I've learnt a lot today  thanks again